# How to test .jar versions?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have a project I'm working on and planning to export as a .jar to be released to public. However a major problem I have with Java is that some things work in Eclipse, but won't as a .jar file (ie directory problems: sometimes the directory is right in Eclipse, but when exported it will no longer work). I would like to know if there is a way to check for errors in a jar file directly in Eclipse. I know you can import the new jar file as an external jar file and run it that way but I don't like having to reimport a new jar file every single time a create a new version of one. What can I do?

Comment: how are you building your jar? with ant?

Comment: There is no such way. You are probably reading files with `java.io.File` where you should use `SomeClass.getResourceAsStream`. This is common problem for new java programmers. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 1):

You can write logs in your code and see that logs in java console when your jar start executing.
how exactly you are building jar ? using command or anything else.?